# 1265, "Data truncated for column 'name' at row 1218

Tags: mysql

I have the following table :

```
desc tr_tmp;
+-------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| aya   | text | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.002 sec)
```

But When I load data from file via :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/mohsen/codes/haq/translation-tmp/ber.mensur.txt'
INTO TABLE tr_tmp  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'  
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (aya);
```

I get the following warnings:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:329: Warning: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'aya' at row 1218")
  self._do_get_result()
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:329: Warning: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'aya' at row 1266")
  self._do_get_result()
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:329: Warning: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'aya' at row 1611")
```

After above warnings, It can't load rest of file.

Comment: The max length of a `TEXT` is 65536 bytes. Are the lines 1218, 1266, and 1611 longer than that?

Comment: @BillKarwin , No, Before them, `LOAD DATA` import bigger than them.

Comment: Keep in mind that the max length of a `TEXT` is in bytes, not characters. So if you use enough multibyte characters, you might exceed 65536 bytes with as few as 16384 characters. Since utf8 characters are variable length, the string you can fit in TEXT may be somewhere in between. You can probably solve this by making your column a `MEDIUMTEXT` which will support up to 16MB (again in bytes, not number of characters).

Comment: wait to test....

Comment: Shit, I got the same warning but only row 1: `1265, "Data truncated for column 'aya_text' at row 1"` @BillKarwin

Comment: Could it be that your file is in Windows format and the lines are terminated by `\r\n`?

Comment: Yes, I'm in UNIX box.

Comment: Oh , After change to mediumtext, I didn't get the error, but when I get `select * from tr_ber_mensur ;` I only watch 1611 rows, If you recall, after 3 truncate warning, last truncate was 1611.

Comment: But the file may still have `\r\n` line terminators if it came from Windows.

Comment: Oh, is it possible the file only has 1611 rows, and it did import all rows? The warnings may not have been fatal. Try `wc -l /home/mohsen/codes/haq/translation-tmp/ber.mensur.txt` to report the number of lines.

Comment: 6236 ./ber.mensur.txt @BillKarwin

Comment: My txt files are 6236 lines. I don't have with other files and according to my script , They imported.

Comment: `select count(*) from tr_ber_mensur; ` : 1611

Comment: I think my file has problem. Because I converted my txt filed into db.

Comment: Well at this point if I were working on this, I would open the file in a text editor and try to examine the lines that are giving those warnings. I suspect the linebreaks are not what you think they are, but that's just a guess. Good luck!